# Class diagram for a simple application

Tags: oop, class, uml, aggregation

Suppose we have 3 entities: Library, Section & Book.

A `Library` consists of several `Sections`. A `Section` has several `Books`.

A `Book` may belong to only 1 `Section`. And finally a `Section` may belong to only 1 `Library`.

The way I see it is that class `Library` **aggregates** a collection of `Sections` and class `Section` **aggregates** a collection of `Books`.

Now I'm required to upload all Books to a server. I build a class `BookUploader` that takes a Book object in its constructor. On the server I created a folder for each Library and inside each library I'll create a Section folder and put the Book in it.

The problem is since I passed a Book object to the BookUploader I have no idea what it's Section is. In addition I don't know which Section belongs to which Library.

So I thought I'll just pass the Library object to the BookUploader then loop all Section then loop all Books in each Section, but someone told me that now BookUploader depends on 3 classes to upload a Book which is a bad design.

He suggested the each Book object should hold it's Section and each Section should hold it's Library which is the total inverse of my original design.

Can anybody share his thoughts on which design is better and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your design force a "book" to be in a single section?  Do you mean it forces an instance of a book to be in a single section?  If so, that is true, but what about multiple "copies" of the same book, those could be spread about in multiple sections unless you're careful to always construct them properly.  Since you're modeling real world situations, think about how it is handled in the real world.  A book is almost always stamped with the library and section information in some manner, and the library/section may also have a list of books that are available...

Comment: @Chad Yes in my design there is only one copy of a Book. My problem is which object should contain the other? should the Library object hold a collection of Sections or should every Section hold a Library object ?

Comment: That seems perfectly appropriate, but back to your original question about how to handle the book->library relationship (opposite of what you've attempted to model so far).  Assume (IRL) you find a library book on the ground outside.  How do you know it's a library book?  Was there some marker on the book to tell you?  I bet there was...

Comment: @Chad +1 Actually you are right. Every Book should know its Library. What I'm missing is a function in the child to get a reference to the parent. Simple point, but it really makes sense once you get a hold of it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @Chad's comment I realized that the design itself needed some modifications to the entities in question.
what was missing is a function in each child class that would return a reference to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with defining aggregation as one end of a bi-directional association. (Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323862.aspx) or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/) for examples.)

If you're looking for implementation details, about that, look e.g. at ecore's [EOpposite](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.2/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EReference.html#getEOpposite()) feature in EReferences.